# NoMethodError in UsersController#create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a super newbie of RoR and following the railstutorial, currently at chapter 2 when you create the first toy app.

I am becoming mad because earlier the creation of users was working... and now I managed to break it :(

when launching http://localhost:3000/users, click create new user, placing name and address and click create user, I now get

> NoMethodError in UsersController#create
> undefined method `title' for #User:0xa5e57d0

and in specific the error seems to be here in - if @user.save

> Extracted source (around line #27):

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save 
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: "User was successfully created." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
```

My class UsersController "concerned area" should be as such

```
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save 
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: "User was successfully created." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Earlier I was able to create correctly two users and now I broke it all and unable to understand what is wrong. Sure it is just something very elementary - please be nice with me, I am a poor newbie.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So it is related to adding in the title attribute.  Did you recently do a migration to add `title` to users?  Is title a field you wanted to add? I was unable to find `title` in the tutorial as I scanned the toy app part, I would recommend doing it exactly as it is at first until you understand how it works.  I assume you never did a migration to add a `title` field to users, correct? To explain a little more, something like `user.email` is calling a method `.email` on the user object.  When you put in `title` if there is no title property added for the use in the DB you will get this error

Comment: Hi! No, I was not changing anything really. I was following everything exactly as it is because as you correctly say I am still understanding how it works. I had added 2 users, created two microposts and all was working correctly. Last thing I did was the part when you set that without filling out one of the fields you get error that you can't leave a field empty. This worked fine with microposts, while it apparently broke user creation even if I don't know why.

Comment: I guess I'll recreate it all from zero and try to understand the exact point that caused the break, even if the events are the ones just listed :( to be honest the tutorial is often skipping parts or imprecise and already several times I found how to fix the steps searching here on Stack, but I seem unable to find anything for that specific error.

Comment: Well just remove where you are calling `.title` on the user, or if you have a filed for `:title` in the form.  Perhaps you just have a typo and put `user.title` in but meant something else?  Can you add the form code into the question? I bet there is something there.